# how to sum values in each row of a column of html table generated from database in jsp using javascript?

Tags: java, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to sum columns of html table generated from database in jsp using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931775/how-to-sum-columns-of-html-table-generated-from-database-in-jsp-using-javascript)

hey i want to sum all the values in one column of html table and get total at the bottom. I am working on jsp. The values in each block is pulled from database so there are no values which have been feeded into the table manually.

I have seen few javascript code which sums the column values but those tables have data which was written manually. for eg 1321 1213654
But my table in jsp page has rows something like this: - <%=size%> <%=area%> where area and size are variables who carry value which was pulled from database.

Can anybody suggest me solution with code? thanks

Comment: Actually, you should do this logic in your *controller* and not in the view. A simple for loop will do it.

Comment: well i'm new to jsp and servlets. If i take help of servlet i can loop it but becomes pretty hard to generate the table over view or have to make getters and setters for every value..i'm confused to be honest. A sample code might help

Answer (score 1):

A very cheap approach would be:

```
int one, two, three... // var for every summation or use a Map<String, ?>
for(Map<String, ?> value : values) {
  for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entries : value.entrySet()) {
    // process your columns and store in the ints or map above
  }
}
```

Now when you are in your JSP and done with displaying your table, present the result in the last row.
The smart programmer does not waste his time for such stuff and uses [displaytag](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/) which does this on request.